# Implementation of RecyclerView with cursor Adapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cursor, sectionedrecyclerviewadapter

How can I implement RecyclerView with the cursor. I tried to implement [this code](https://gist.github.com/skyfishjy/443b7448f59be978bc59) but this code uses some class to store each row but I did not want to make some class for the sake of storing each row of the cursor. And also I found this [article](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/121353/recycler-view-with-cursor-adapter) which says that we don't need to make class when using the cursor. I am confused which approach to use and how to use it. I tried to implement most of the code present on stackOverFlow but they all are almost same.

And also i tried my code with this:

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.MyViewHolder>{
    private Cursor cursor;
    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView title,text;
        CardView cd;
        LinearLayout ll;
        public MyViewHolder(View v){
            super(v);
            title = v.findViewById(R.id.childTitleView);
            text = v.findViewById(R.id.childTextView);
            cd = v.findViewById(R.id.parentCardView);
            ll = v.findViewById(R.id.ll);
         }

    }

    public RecyclerViewAdapter(Cursor c){
        this.cursor = c;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return cursor.getCount();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        cursor.moveToNext();
        String t = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(RecordContract.RecordEntry.COLUMN_TITLE));
        String d = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(RecordContract.RecordEntry.COLUMN_TEXT));
        holder.title.setText(t);
        holder.text.setText(d);
        holder.cd.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), ""+position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //holder.ll.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000"));
                holder.cd.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(view.getResources().getString(R.color.blueGreen)));
                return true;
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_view_child,parent,false);
        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }
}
```

This is My MainActivity

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mdb = new RecordDbHelper(getApplicationContext());

        RecyclerView rv = findViewById(R.id.recylerViewId);
        rv.setLayoutManager(new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2,StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
        rv.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        Cursor c = getCursor();
        RecyclerViewAdapter rva = new RecyclerViewAdapter(c);
        rv.setAdapter(rva);
  }

   public Cursor getCursor(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = mdb.getReadableDatabase();
        String[] projection = {
            RecordContract.RecordEntry._ID,  RecordContract.RecordEntry.COLUMN_TEXT,
            RecordContract.RecordEntry.COLUMN_TITLE};
        String selection = null;
        String[] selectionArgs = null;
        String tableName = RecordContract.RecordEntry.TABLE_NAME;
        Cursor c = db.query(tableName,projection,selection,selectionArgs,null,null,null);
        return c;
    }
```

Well this show the text in the RecyclerView But when a new data is added to the database then the app requires to start again. It does not refresh itself.

Comment: why you need to pass cursor in adapter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Well this show the text in the RecyclerView

It will not do so reliably. In `onBindViewHolder()`, replace `moveToNext()` with `moveToPosition(position)`. Right now, you are ignoring the `position` parameter, which means as soon as you start scrolling (particularly backwards), you will run into problems.

> But when a new data is added to the database then the app requires to start again. It does not refresh itself.

That is no different than how `CursorAdapter` works with an `AdapterView`, such as a `ListView`.

When you update the database, you need to get a fresh `Cursor` and hand it to your  `RecyclerViewAdapter`. Your `RecyclerViewAdapter` can then call `notifyDataSetChanged()` to tell the `RecyclerView` to redraw itself.

Comment: Is my method of accessing cursor in onBindViewHolder() correct?

Comment: @MayankDoda: As I mentioned, you need to replace `moveToNext()` with `moveToPosition(position)`. Otherwise, I do not see any problems with it. Personally, I would have most of that logic be in the `ViewHolder`, with `onBindViewHolder()` simply calling `moveToPosition()` and passing the `Cursor` to the `ViewHolder` to do the actual binding.

Comment: can you help implementing the code for onResume function. i tried to use rva.notifydataSetChanged() in onResume but it doesnot work.

Comment: @MayankDoda: Sorry, but I do not know what you are doing in `onResume()` and I do not know what "doesnot work" means in this context. You might consider asking a separate Stack Overflow question, where you provide a fresh [mcve] and explain in detail the nature of your problem.

Comment: for refreshing the recyclerView I was trying to use notifyDataSetChanged() method but RecyclerView doesn't update. It is showing the same data

Comment: @MayankDoda: Your `RecyclerView.Adapter` needs to be in position to work with the new data at that point. If your `RecyclerView.Adapter` still has your old `Cursor`, you will not see any changes. [This sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v8.11/RecyclerView/VideoList) is the closest that I have to your scenario (though I'll have some closer ones coming out in a few weeks). In my case, I switch from a `null` `Cursor` to one delivered to me by the `CursorLoader`. I call `notifyDataSetChanged()` to get the `RecyclerView` to ask for new stuff from my adapter.